# Is there a way to 'map' arrays in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm looking for an elegant way to map entries in an array, other than a for-loop that creates a new array. For example

```
class A;
  int int_member;
endclass

A class_container[$];
int int_members_only[$];

initial begin
  // Assume class_container is populated

  // 'map' is not an available function 
  int_members_only= class_container.map(x) with (x.int_member);

  // Yes, you can do this but I want to know if there's another way
  foreach (class_container[i_class]) begin
    int_members_only.push_back(class_container[i_class].int_member);
  end
end
```

Comment: for my taste, the *foreach* solution is **more** elegant than your  *map* attempt. At least it is readable :-)

Comment: @Serge The `map` style is common in Python and other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in SystemVerilog that does this kind of mapping. The closest feature directly for your example is the streaming operator. (11.4.14 Streaming operators (pack/unpack)), but that only works if there is only one member in the class. I assume that is not the general case you need.